# Problems with spaces in paths when calling a batch file from R

Tags: r, batch-file, system, command-prompt

I have some problems to call a command line program called molconvert from R using `system()` in Windows. molconvert is located in `"C:\Program Files\ChemAxon\MarvinBeans\bin"`
I would then like to invoke `system()` or `shell()` to mimick what I would achieve by typing

```
molconvert pdb "C:\molecule conversions\cembrene A.mol"
```

at the command prompt and collect the resulting output back to R as in

```
out=system(...,intern=T)
```

I seem to have trouble though with the backslashes and the spaces in the paths.
I tried with

```
dirmolconvert="C:\\Program Files\\ChemAxon\\MarvinBeans\\bin"
shell(shQuote(paste(dirmolconvert,"\\molconvert pdb "C:\\cembrene A.mol",sep="")))
```

but that gives me "Error: unexpected symbol in ..." and escaping the " also doesn't help. Any thoughts on how I should resolve this?

or

```
system(paste(dirmolconvert,"\\molconvert pdb \"C:\\cembrene A.mol\"",sep=""), intern=T)
```

but that gives me

```
'C:\Program' not found
```

Any thoughts?

Edit:
Based on the answer below the right way to do this apparently is

```
inputdir="C:/Users/Ento/Documents/GCMS/molconvert test"
molconvertdir="C:/Program Files/ChemAxon/MarvinBeans/bin"
molecule="cembrene A.mol"
out=system(paste(shQuote(file.path(molconvertdir, "molconvert.bat")),
             "pdb",
             shQuote(file.path(inputdir,molecule))),intern=T)
```

Comment: If I use this syntax:  `system('../rgames/test space/norun.bat')` I have no error messages.  See if you can do the same with your path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `shQuote` to quote the *path to the executable*, not the entire command line. Depending on what your molconvert program expects, you may also want to quote paths that are arguments to it.

```
system(paste(shQuote(file.path(dirmolconvert, "molconvert.exe")),
             "pdb",
             shQuote("C:\\molecule conversions\\cembrene A.mol"))
```

Comment: Ha many thanks! That did it! And yes, I also need to quote the paths in the argument!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to fix this is to use short paths:

```
for %%a in ("C:\molecule conversions\cembrene A.mol") set "sh_path=%%~dpfnxsa"
```

or

```
for %%a in ("C:\Program Files\ChemAxon\MarvinBeans\bin") do set "pf_sh_path=%%~dpfnxsa"
```

and then to pass `%sh_path%` and `%pf_sh_path%` as parameter.

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite understand - you mean I should put this in a batch file, and then call this batch file from R? But is there no way in which I can do it all directly in R, without first having to make a batch file?

Comment: You can call the `R` from batch and pass these as command line parameters...I've never used `R` but you can check if you can get short names with it.