# tar.gz not installing for R 3.4

Tags: r

I have R 3.4 and would like to install superheat. I tried

```
install.packages("C://Users//me//Downloads//superheat-0.1.0.tar.gz")
```

and got a warning in install.packages:

```
package ‘C://Users//me//Downloads//superheat-0.1.0.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)n error
```

Do I need an earlier version of R?

Comment: You may want to try `install.packages("superheat")` instead. This will download the package from one of the CRAN mirrors. `install.packages` also accepts local files but it appears they need to be prepended with `file://`. You're example is trying to search for a package called `C://Users//me//Downloads//superheat-0.1.0.tar.gz` which doesn't exist on CRAN.

Comment: If you want to install a package from a local file you need to set `repos = NULL` in the call to `install.packages`.  Also, you probably only need one `/` between your directories in your file path.